# EDIT html file in vb.net

Tags: css, vb.net, html

I've created a html page which consists of a div section in the body tag.

How do I change the contents of inner divs based on an event in another in vb.net winform(eg: when a button is pressed)?

```
   <div id="magazine">   
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/01.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/02.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/03.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/04.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/05.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/06.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/07.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/08.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please give more information about what are you working with. Right now it sounds to me like you are working with vb.net WEBforms (asp.net). Are you working on windows application? How it works with your HTML file? How it is create, how you display it, where it is stored? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Give each of the DIVs an ID and runat="server" attribute.  You should then be able to reference each one from server side code.

Comment: Actually, I've noticed that you want to do this from a webform.  Perhaps this is only part of the solution.  You could simply try editing the file directly - read it into a variable process it, spit it back out to the file, refresh your display.